# Trigger compile error

Tags: plsql

Below is my trigger for which I am getting compile errors:

```
Error(3,5): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(4,5): PL/SQL: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
Error(26,9): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(37,9): PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
Error(48,50): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "RECORD" when expecting one of the following:     ) , * & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem =>    <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2    like4 likec as between from using || multiset member    submultiset
```

```
create or replace 
TRIGGER DSP_MAIN.TRG_DSP_TXN_INS_UPD
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
ON DSP_MAIN.DSP_TRANSACTION_DTLS REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING THEN
    INSERT INTO  DSP_HIST.DSP_TRANSACTION_DTLS_HISTORY(
    VALUES (
    :NEW.TXN_ID,
    :NEW.SESSION_ID,
    :NEW.TXN_STATUS_ID,     
    :NEW.STATE_ID,
    :NEW.OPERATION_ID,
    :NEW.UBIGEO,  
    :NEW.DISTRICT,
    :NEW.DOC_TYPE,
    :NEW.DOC_VALUE,
    :NEW.TARIFF_PLAN,
    :NEW.DATA_PROTECT,
    :NEW.CONTRACT_ACCEPT,
    :NEW.BIO_RESULT,
    :NEW.LAST_STATUS_MOD_TIME,
    :NEW.LAST_STATE_MOD_TIME,
    :NEW.REQUEST_START_TIME,
    :NEW.REQUEST_END_TIME,
    :NEW.INCIDENT_ID,
    :NEW.NON_BIO_RESULT    
    ); 
    ELSIF UPDATING THEN
        UPDATE DSP_HIST_TEST.DSP_TRANSACTION_DTLS_HISTORY SET
        SESSION_ID = :NEW.SESSION_ID,     
        TXN_STATUS_ID = :NEW.TXN_STATUS_ID,
        STATE_ID = :NEW.STATE_ID,
        OPERATION_ID = :NEW.OPERATION_ID,
        UBIGEO = :NEW.UBIGEO,    
        DISTRICT = :NEW.DISTRICT,
        DOC_TYPE = :NEW.DOC_TYPE,
        DOC_VALUE = :NEW.DOC_VALUE,
        TARIFF_PLAN = :NEW.TARIFF_PLAN,
        DATA_PROTECT = :NEW.DATA_PROTECT
        CONTRACT_ACCEPT = :NEW.CONTRACT_ACCEPT
        BIO_RESULT = :NEW.BIO_RESULT
        LAST_STATUS_MOD_TIME = :NEW.LAST_STATUS_MOD_TIME
        LAST_STATE_MOD_TIME = :NEW.LAST_STATE_MOD_TIME
        REQUEST_START_TIME = :NEW.REQUEST_START_TIME
        REQUEST_END_TIME = :NEW.REQUEST_END_TIME
        INCIDENT_ID = :NEW.INCIDENT_ID
        NON_BIO_RESULT = :NEW.NON_BIO_RESULT

    WHERE TXN_ID = :OLD.TXN_ID;
    END IF;
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Record successfull UPDATED IN DSP TRANSACTION HISTORY TABLE');
  END;
```

is that something i m doing wrong on syntax?

Comment: `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('R...'`);

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I changed the line actually after adding the question and also added missing commas but still i see some errors:

Comment: btw your output message 'Record successfull UPDATED...' will be also be shown when you have INSERTED. (And it's _'successfully'_, and the message goes all-uppercase halfway through for no obvious reason.) A bigger problem though is that inserting or updating a lot of rows could exceed the serveroutput setting in the client and cause the whole thing to fail.

Answer (score 1):

There is a paranthesis which does not belong here. After ...DTLS_HISTORY

```
INSERT INTO  DSP_HIST.DSP_TRANSACTION_DTLS_HISTORY
values(.....);
```

Also there are a lot of missing commas in the update statement

```
UPDATE DSP_HIST_TEST.DSP_TRANSACTION_DTLS_HISTORY SET
        SESSION_ID = :NEW.SESSION_ID,     
        TXN_STATUS_ID = :NEW.TXN_STATUS_ID,
        STATE_ID = :NEW.STATE_ID,
        OPERATION_ID = :NEW.OPERATION_ID,
        UBIGEO = :NEW.UBIGEO,    
        DISTRICT = :NEW.DISTRICT,
        DOC_TYPE = :NEW.DOC_TYPE,
        DOC_VALUE = :NEW.DOC_VALUE,
        TARIFF_PLAN = :NEW.TARIFF_PLAN,
        DATA_PROTECT = :NEW.DATA_PROTECT,
        CONTRACT_ACCEPT = :NEW.CONTRACT_ACCEPT,
        BIO_RESULT = :NEW.BIO_RESULT,
        LAST_STATUS_MOD_TIME = :NEW.LAST_STATUS_MOD_TIME,
        LAST_STATE_MOD_TIME = :NEW.LAST_STATE_MOD_TIME,
        REQUEST_START_TIME = :NEW.REQUEST_START_TIME,
        REQUEST_END_TIME = :NEW.REQUEST_END_TIME,
        INCIDENT_ID = :NEW.INCIDENT_ID,
        NON_BIO_RESULT = :NEW.NON_BIO_RESULT

    WHERE TXN_ID = :OLD.TXN_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess DBMS_OUTPUT statement is causing issue. You may change it to this.

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Record successfull UPDATED IN DSP TRANSACTION HISTORY TABLE');
```